# Generating multiple amounts of the same sprite broken

Tags: c++, sfml

I have just started working on a 2d game of mine. I'm currently experiencing a problem where I am trying to make some land with a grass block texture by spawning the same sprites multiple times with the same grass texture. However, instead of getting a row of the same texture, I am getting the row being stretched for some reason.
Let me show you:
Normal grass texture:

[image: normal grass]

Current grass output:

[image: current grass]

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main() {
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1920, 1080), "Treko");
    Color bg(0, 205, 255);
    Font errorFont;
    Texture grass;
    Texture dirt;
    if (!errorFont.loadFromFile("font/Arial/Arial.ttf")) {
        RenderWindow error(VideoMode(600, 500), "Error!");
        Text errorText;
        errorText.setFont(errorFont);
        errorText.setString("Unfortunaetly, we are unable to find Arial.ttf.\nPlease reinstall the application and report the error. Thank you.");
        errorText.setCharacterSize(18);
        errorText.setFillColor(Color::White);
        while (error.isOpen()) {
            Event errorEvent;
            while (error.pollEvent(errorEvent)) {
                if (errorEvent.type == Event::Closed) {
                    error.close();
                }
            }
            error.clear();
            error.draw(errorText);
            error.display();
        }
    }
    if (!dirt.loadFromFile("img/Dirt.png")) {
        RenderWindow error(VideoMode(600, 500), "Error!");
        Text errorText;
        errorText.setFont(errorFont);
        errorText.setString("Unfortunaetly, we are unable to find Dirt.png.\nPlease reinstall the application and report the error. Thank you.");
        errorText.setCharacterSize(18);
        while (error.isOpen()) {
            Event errorEvent;
            while (error.pollEvent(errorEvent)) {
                if (errorEvent.type == Event::Closed) {
                    error.close();
                }
            }
            error.clear();
            error.draw(errorText);
            error.display();
        }
    }
    if (!grass.loadFromFile("img/Grass.png")) {
        RenderWindow error(VideoMode(600, 500), "Error!");
        Text errorText;
        errorText.setFont(errorFont);
        errorText.setString("Unfortunaetly, we are unable to find Grass.png.\nPlease reinstall the application and report the error. Thank you.");
        errorText.setCharacterSize(18);
        errorText.setFillColor(Color::White);
        while (error.isOpen()) {
            Event errorEvent;
            while (error.pollEvent(errorEvent)) {
                if (errorEvent.type == Event::Closed) {
                    error.close();
                }
            }
            error.clear();
            error.draw(errorText);
            error.display();
        }
    }
    Sprite grassBlock;
    grassBlock.setTexture(grass);
    Sprite dirtBlock;
    dirtBlock.setTexture(dirt);
    vector<Sprite> grassM;
    /* This is a work in progress. I'm trying to add height to the land using random y axis generation. Any of you know how to do this it would be great to let me know!
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> randomColorRange(680, 720);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 RandYPos(rd());
    */
//THE PROBLEM PART 1
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1918; i++) {
        grassBlock.setPosition(Vector2f(i + 1, 690));
        grassBlock.setScale(Vector2f(0.5f, 0.5f));
        grassM.push_back(Sprite(grassBlock));
    }
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.clear(bg);
//THE PROBLEM PART 2
        for (int i = 0; i < grassM.size(); i++) {
            window.draw(grassM[i]);
        }
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone knows how to do this, that would be great!

Comment: didnt read your code, though the image looks like its only one and the same column, not just the streched image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I didn't try to run the code, to me it looks like everything is working. Your problem is, that you're just moving the sprites one pixel apart:

```
grassBlock.setPosition(Vector2f(i + 1, 690));
```

Since all show the same texture with the same origin, this will result in all the sprites essentially showing the first column of your texture (since the rest is overlapped by the next tile).

While I think you should rework your whole code structure (it feels really messy and I wouldn't recommend to create new SFML windows if you encounter errors, since that might fail as well), all you have to do is move your sprites apart by multiplying the index used for your coordinate by the desired tile width:

```
grassBlock.setPosition(Vector2f(i * tile_width, 690));
```

Comment: how do you get the width of the sprite/tile?

Comment: @HarveyGray You can query the texture's size, if you don't change the sprite after assigning it.